# Seafile Client does not connect to server with HTTPS anymore

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh

Using Seafile Client 4.2.4. and Seafile Server 4.2.2 on Raspberry Pi I get the following when trying to sync a library:

[image]

Here is my nginx config (source: [Installing Seafile on Raspberry Pi](http://draptik.github.io/blog/2014/04/21/installing-seafile-on-raspberry-pi/)):

```
server {
    listen 8001; # <--------------------------------------- NGINX PORT
    ssl on; # <-------------------------------------------- SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/seahub.crt; # <--------- SSL
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/seahub.key; # <----- SSL
    server_name myserver.no-ip.biz.tld; # <----------------- CHANGE THIS
    error_page 497  https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:8000;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO           $fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR         $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT         $server_port;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME         $server_name;
        fastcgi_param   HTTPS   on;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_SCHEME https;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/seahub.access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/seahub.error.log;
    }
    location /seafhttp {
        rewrite ^/seafhttp(.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        client_max_body_size 0;
    }

    location /media {
        root /home/seafile/seafile/seafile-server-latest/seahub; # <-- change: 2014-07-11
        # include /etc/nginx/mime.types; # <--- UNCOMMENT THIS IF CSS FILES AREN'T LOADED
    }
}
```

Here is my `seahub_settings.py`:

```
SECRET_KEY = "-some key"
HTTP_SERVER_ROOT = 'https://myserver.no-ip.biz:8001/seafhttp'
```

On Seafile client I use the server address:

```
https://myserver.no-ip.biz:8001
```

When I connect to the server with a web browser https works great. On Seafile client I can only connect with HTTP.

**How can I connect to Seafile server from Seafile client with HTTPS?**

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem as I enable the checkbox "do not verify server certificate in HTTPS syncing" in seafile settings. The certificate on my nginx server  is self signed.

[image]